# What's a good Font Manager for OS X?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

I am searching for a good font manager for Lion. It should work especially with [google web fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts).

I need a good overview of non-alphabetic unicode characters. And activating/deactivating would be great i.e. to check, if web pages I work on work well with fonts being installed or not.

So basically I need a font manager, that supports me for developing websites.

Comment: Could you be more specific in your requirements? Any reason not to use Font Book?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Font Case](http://www.bohemiancoding.com/fontcase) is the app you are looking for. It has activation/deactivation, web preview mode, glyph overviews, collections etc.

Comment: Does it work with Google Web Fonts?